# Wpf C# - Change the Metro Label foreground color

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, mahapps.metro

I am using the Mahapps.Metro but when i try to change the color of its text it states white.

How can I override the color of the label? I want to be able to override it in XAML as well as in the background code in C# as I want to incorporate my ColorAnimation as well for mouseovers and stuff.

Regards,

Simon

Comment: try reading your question before posting and check if someone else can follow it. `when I try to change the color of its text` What "text"?. `How can I override the color of the label?` which `Label`? the control? just set `Foreground`, or is it the Window title you're talking about? Mahapps.Metro comes with a bunch of `ResourceDictionary`'s you could have added / missed. Post what you've actually got in your xaml for someone to even make a rough guess.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue.

The problem is that if you leave in the resourcedictionnary the line stating:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml"/>
```

then you can not override a control's colour for foreground if it is a control that is styled by the Mahapps.Metro dll.